# Difference between mutable, specified and effective repository permissions in GitBLIT

Tags: git, permissions, gitblit

I am using Gitblit as web-frontend for git and i am curious what is the difference between mutable, specified and effective repository permission in git?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I believe Rob Conaway & Jame Moger, these are the rules :

- Repo permissions can only be maintained by an owner of the repo.  If you are not the owner, it will appear to let you change the permissions, but actually fail silently
- Mutable are the permissions you can change through that control
- Specified includes mutable + owners
- Effective is specified + regex, admins, etc

---

[source](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gitblit/ia1u5He8AWk/discussion)